Cannot disable Fast Deployment in Visual Studio 2022 .Net Maui Android project
Our .Net Maui project had several custom configurations created in conjunction with the standard configurations before I joined the project as follows:

Debug - Standard
Release - Standard
RELEASE_UAT - Custom
RELEASE_PROD - Custom

I am trying to change just the RELEASE_PROD configuration so it does not use fast deployment and has a file format of app bundle.  However, the properties for the project do not seem to let me make such changes.
Below is what the Android settings look like in the Project Properties.  (FYI - It does not matter which configuration I have selected in VS - these properties always show the same values)

I cannot turn off the Fast Deployment options for RELEASE_UAT or RELEASE_PROD on this screen.  If I click on the check box for RELEASE_UAT or RELEASE_PROD, nothing happens.  If I  click on the check box for debug, I can turn it on and off.
Also below are the values for the configurations from the CSharp Project.
    <!-- Debug -->
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
     <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)-debug</AssemblyName>
     <ApplicationId>com.ups.gsl.presentation</ApplicationId>
     <ApplicationTitle>GSL</ApplicationTitle>
     <EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>True</EmbedAssembliesIntoApk>
     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
     <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
     <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
     <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <!-- Release -->
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='RELEASE_PROD|net8.0-android|AnyCPU'">
     <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
     <ApplicationId>com.ups.gsl.presentation</ApplicationId>
     <ApplicationTitle>GSL</ApplicationTitle>
     <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
     <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>-->
     <AndroidPackageFormat>aab</AndroidPackageFormat>
     <AndroidUseAapt2>True</AndroidUseAapt2>
     <AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>False</AndroidCreatePackagePerAbi>
   </PropertyGroup>

------UPDATE-------
I can replicate the challenge on a brand new .Net 8 Maui project with the following steps:

Create a new .Net 8 Maui project in Visual Studio 2022.
Right click on the solution in the solution explorer and select Configuration Manager.
Under Active solution configuration drop down, select <New...>
Name the new configuration RELEASE_PROD and select to copy the settings from Release. Ensure the Create new project configuration check box is checked and click the OK button.
Close the configuration manager window.
Right mouse button click on your .net maui project in the solution explorer and select Properties from the popup menu.
In the left hand pane go down to Android and expand it and click on options.
Change the Android Package Format for RELEASE_PROD & net8.0-android to bundle.

Your screen should now look as follows:


Now attempt to turn off Fast Deployment for RELEASE_PROD & net8.0-android.

You cannot turn off the option.

I opened a defect with MS here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Unable-to-turn-off-Fast-Deployment-for-/10628674?port=1025&fsid=b923d4e8-e687-40a1-be2f-8b60e4d440a7&sort=newest&ref=native&refTime=1711999354942&refUserId=00e77b39-8857-6d92-940d-a1c598768143
And would still appreciate any work around someone might have to we can make out production build with having to redo all our configuration profiles.

I reproduced the question you described on VS 2022-17.9.5 and VS 2022-17.10.0 Preview 2.0 (they are all the latest versions). You can also report it on issue of MAUI on GitHub.
